# webpack-cli [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/resource']

Tags: webpack-5

I want to copy the static file in webpack 5.x, so I install the webpack copy plugin     `"copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.1",` and added config like this:

```
new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "src/manifest.json", to: "manifest.json" },
        { from: "src/resource/image", to: "/resource/image" },
      ],
    }),
```

what I am trying to do is copy the image folder from source folder to dist folder and keep the folder structure. But when I run the webpack command and shows error like this:

```
➜  reddwaf-translate-plugin git:(main) ✗ npm run dev

> reddwaf-translate-plugin@1.0.0 dev
> rm -rf src/bundle && webpack --mode development --config src/resource/config/webpack.dev.config.js

[webpack-cli] [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/resource'] {
  errno: -30,
  code: 'EROFS',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/resource'
}
```

I am sure the filesystem is not read only because I have created files and folder. why did this happen? what should I do to fix it? The current operation system is macOS Monteney with M1 pro chip.

Answer (score 8):

I finally figure out what was happen, I config the folder start with a slash means that will create a folder resource in the root of macOS filesystem. That why the error happen, just remove the root slash will fix this problem.

```
new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "src/manifest.json", to: "manifest.json" },
        { from: "src/resource/image", to: "resource/image" },
      ],
    }),
```

it will create the folder structure in the dist folder.

Comment: Dang, i had been struggling to fix this simple error. thank you